# What is import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;

Tags: java, jdbc

As part of my project I am trying to connect it with database. I searched in google for the code and I got the following code. In that I don't understand 2 things - "import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;" and "new Driver". What do these 2 mean ?

```
package javasql;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;
import java.sql.*;

public class Connect {
public Connect() throws SQLException{
    makeConnection();
} 

private Connection koneksi;  

 public  Connection makeConnection() throws SQLException {
    if (koneksi == null) {
         new Driver();
        // buat koneksi
         koneksi = DriverManager.getConnection(
                   "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql","root","virus");
     }
     return koneksi;
 }  

 public static void main(String args[]) {
     try {
         Connect c = new Connect();
         System.out.println("Connection established");
     }
     catch (SQLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.err.println("Connection Failure");
     }  

}
}
```

---

```
package javasql;

import java.sql.*;

public class SqlStatement {
private Statement statement;
public SqlStatement() throws SQLException{
    makeStatement();
}
public Statement makeStatement() throws SQLException{
    Connect c = new Connect();
    Connection conn = c.makeConnection();
    statement = conn.createStatement();
    return statement;
}
public void insert(String name,int npm)throws SQLException{
    statement.execute("insert into Student values(\""+name+"\","+npm+");");
}
public static void main(String arg[]){
    try {
        SqlStatement s = new SqlStatement();
        s.insert("Ferdi2",3);
        s.insert("Anca2",3);
        System.out.println("Success");
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("Failed");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I use NetBeans IDE to develop my project. When I used these codes I made it as a new project. Then it worked fine. But whenever I tried to include these codes in another projects errors are showing at "import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;". Why is it so ? Can I use these 2 codes in another projects ?

Comment: You have to include a driver library to be able to interact with an database management system. `import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` is the class of a mysql driver that yoyu must have in your class path.
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Comment: You need to include the MYSQL java library with your project. The import statement tells the compiler you are using a class called `Driver` from package `com.mysql.jdbc`.

Comment: Thanks... When I added the MySQL JDBC Driver in NetBeans the problem is solved.

Comment: Note that the new Driver() line is just wrong; I would remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The driver serves as an interface between your application and the database.

Are you using MySQL?  If so, you can find the MySQl Java drivers [here.](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/)

Comment: Thanks. This was my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using `import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;` in `JDBC` code is not a good practice 
and you need to import only `java.sql.*` and `javax.sql.*`. The reason is to detach the code from the specific driver implementation.

See [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html) for more information how to make JDBC connections. And `DriverManager.getConnection(...)` is enough to get connection.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is

// This will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver 
      `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")`

This acts like class loader and load your driver class for you. For that you need to add the corresponding jar file.