# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver error even after importing library

Tags: java, mysql, database, eclipse, jdbc

I have imported my library "mysql-connector-java-5.1.39"
as answered by most people to exact same question , 
but I am still getting this error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

here is the code of test class

```
package database;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        getConnection();
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
        try{
            String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
            String username="root";
            String password="root";
            Class.forName(driver);
            Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
            System.out.println("connected");
            return conn;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

[image: eclipse directory]

Using mac OS .

Comment: Did you add the .jar file to build path?

Comment: `Class.forName(driver);` for `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` i don't see it imported in your Main class

Comment: Check your referenced libraries.  Apparently your compiler doesn't see 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'.  Also even if you have imported your jar, are you sure that this specific class is in that jar?

Comment: i added zip file to build bath > add external jars. 
i downloaded connector file from mysql official site it should have that class or not ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everybody repeat after me.  ( :-) )

> "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" is NOT a compilation error.

Therefore, changing the >>build<< path or adding an `import` cannot fix the problem.

The solution is to make sure that the JAR file is on the classpath when you run the application.  For example, if your test class is in `bin\database\Main.class` and the driver JAR is in `lib` ...

```
$ java -classpath bin:lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar database.Main
```

Answer (score 2):

***If the jar is already added to your external libs***, you can simply add :

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;
```

and it shall work in your class.

This shall help further [SO-21580499](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580499/what-is-import-com-mysql-jdbc-driver)

Comment: You need to add the jar for the lib to your project as an external library. Then it shall work, the if clause in my answer.

Comment: Sir ! I added connector zip file to build bath > add external jars.which  i downloaded from mysql official site

Comment: I don't think that import statement is required. Class.forName uses reflection to get the class instance, and import is not required. Import is checked and resolved at the compile time.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the most possible reasons of "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" in your code are:

1. You don't have mysql-connector.jar in your Classpath.
2. mysql-connector.jar is in your classpath but somehow your classpath is getting overridden.
3. mysql-connector.jar is in classpath but current user doesn't have read permission.

Comment: i have added connector zip from mysq site and added it through build path . it should be in class path or not ?

Comment: Did you add zip file itself or its jar which is inside it ? You need to add jar not zip. It should be in your class path if you are running your program manually - Otherwise if you are using IDE then it will automatically from the lib directory where you have added it.

Comment: i was adding zip , now added jar file by placing it in class path and its done :)

Comment: Nice. Good. All the best with your rest of the project.

Comment: The solution proposed by @MeisterAjit in the above comment is the only one that worked for me. I had added the ZIP instead of the JAR in Eclipse. An elementary bug that Eclipse needs to address.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you app cannot find the JDBC driver for Microsoft SQL server. You can download it below and add the jar to your WEB-INF/lib:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are missing any one of the following things : Both of the following things are necessary to remove the error :

1. Adding mysql-connector.jar file to your **WebContent / WEB-INF / lib** folder.
2. Adding mysql-connector.jar file in your classpath

Download mysql-connector.jar from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.11

For solving first problem paste the above downloaded jar file into your project's **WebContent / WEB-INF / lib** folder.

For Solving second problem - right click on your project , go to **properties** then go to **Java Build Path** and then in **Libraries** *section* choose *Add External JARs* and select the above downloaded jar file.

Hope it helps.