# ClassNotFound Exception for "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" even after adding mysql-con.jar file

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have already set the classpath to mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar and compiled my class successfully.
But when I run it I get:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

The code is:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class JdbcExample
{

    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://loacalhost:3306/sample","root","root");
            Statement st=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from sample");
            while(rs.next())
            {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            }
            con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to follow these links, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585811/classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484764/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver-in-eclipse

Comment: yup...in all these links people used some IDE...which I did not. They all messed up in placing the jar in the wrong folder. That is not the case here. I am not using an IDE. Plus kindly note that the class compiled successfully when I used javac -cp "my classpath" filename.java... Check this link's answer by Stephen to understand the problem better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43918756/classnotfound-exception-for-com-mysql-jdbc-driver-even-after-adding-mysql-con?stw=2

Comment: I tried stephen's solution of mentioning the jar classpath even while running...but it did not work...

Comment: Are you using eclipse or some IDE for this? Clearly the jar is not on the classpath somehow. Assuming your java file is in C:\test directory, can u try putting the jar file also in the same directory and then run the java code?

Comment: kindly check the link I mentioned in my comment above ...u are not understanding the problem...and no I didnt use an IDE.. had jar unavailability been the problem... the class would not have compiled...

Comment: @RakshitPRVashishta the link from your comment above is just pointing back to this question... Please post HOW your are executing your program

Comment: I agree  with @Carlos Heuberger

Comment: sorry wrong link ...wait for a minute I will give the correct link

Comment: the link isn't that important, but we need to know how you are starting your program, more precisely, how are you "adding" the driver JAR (and which JAR it is) - Is the mysql connector called "mysql-con.jar"?

Comment: I compiled using javac -cp mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar JdbcExample.java and it compiled successfully...but on running I got this exception

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37254131/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver-error-even-after-importi  here's the link that I was talking about

Comment: see my answer below... the driver is not used for compilation only on execution - the link is also very clear about that: "...when you run the application... `java -classpath...`" (-cp == -classpath)

Comment: Can you put the mysql jar in the JRE lib directory and then try running? Do a echo %JAVA_HOME%(windows) or whereis java(Ubuntu) from command line to get the home directory and go to its lib dir and paste the mysql file there and then try to run?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are "adding" the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.42-bin.jar` file to the classpath when starting your program (obviously it can be a different version number).

something like

```
java -cp .;mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar JdbcExample
```

or

```
set CLASSPATH=...;mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar
java JdbcExample
```

assuming:

1. the JAR is in the current folder... if that works, consider putting the JAR in a 'central' place a use the complete path in above commands
2. using Windows, otherwise the separator would be `:` instead of `;`
3. the class is in no package

for Ubuntu:

```
java -cp .:mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar JdbcExample
```

Comment: mysql-connector-java-5.1.42-bin.jar: command not found the jar is in the current folder,

Comment: mysql-connector-java-5.1.42-bin.jar: command not found this is what I get

Comment: I checked , the jar is in the currrent folder, I am using ubuntu, and the class is in no package

Comment: you have to use the driver you got - ...5.0.8-bin.jar - this answer was wrotten BEFORE you have given us the correct driver name.  READ the end of my first sentence above: `(obviously it can be a different version number)`

Comment: changed answer to reflect the version you mentioned in the question's comment

Comment: yup...that was by mistake...but I still get a whole description of options to use with java alongwith command not found

Comment: it would be VERY USEFUL to see the command you are using!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! best to add it to the question!

Comment: The ';' was wrong. ':' works. Thanks bro...can u just explain it to me...why is the ':' required?

Comment: to separate the different entries - you are allowed to use more than one JAR, e.g. one or more for databases, for logging, for graphics, ... actually you can also add folders where to search for CLASS files

Comment: have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html for an overview

Answer (score 0):

Looks like more of a classpath issue. Try adding the jar manually to your project. I ran the same with `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8.jar` and I dont get this error.

Comment: kindly follow up through all comments to my question before answering..u have not understood the problem.

Comment: again pls read through before suggesting links.... I have been through the entire process before asking the question..